# Java on ServiceBus for Windows Server- Options?

Tags: java, azure, servicebus

What are the options available to develop Java applications using Service Bus for Windows?

1. Java Message Broker API  - This need ACS to work with, which SB for Win doesnt support.
2. AMQP - This doesnt seem to work on SB for Windows, I keep getting error

   org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender$SenderCreationException: Peer did not create remote endpoint for link, target:

While the same code works with Azure SB. So AMQP on SB for Windows seems to be not fully working?

Correct me if I have missed something?

**Update**
To test AMQP on local machine, this is what I did

1. Installed Service  bus 1.1 on my local machine
2. Took the sample mentioned here http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/how-to-guides/service-bus-amqp/
3. Created a new namespace on my local machine
4. Specified the following connection string in servicebus.properties (which is correctly referred in the code

   `connectionfactory.SBCF = amqps://<username>:<password>@<MachineName>:5671/StringAnalyzerNS/`

   `queue.QUEUE = queue1`

Code is updated with certificates.

At runtime I get this error

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Peer did not create remote endpoint for link, target: queue1
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.MessageProducerImpl.<init>(MessageProducerImpl.java:77)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.SessionImpl.createProducer(SessionImpl.java:348)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.SessionImpl.createProducer(SessionImpl.java:63)
    at com.stringcompany.Analyzer.SimpleSenderReceiver.<init>(SimpleSenderReceiver.java:70)
    at com.stringcompany.Analyzer.SimpleSenderReceiver.main(SimpleSenderReceiver.java:95)
Caused by: org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender$SenderCreationException: Peer did not create remote endpoint for link, target: queue1
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender.<init>(Sender.java:171)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender.<init>(Sender.java:104)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender.<init>(Sender.java:97)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender.<init>(Sender.java:83)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender.<init>(Sender.java:69)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender.<init>(Sender.java:63)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Session.createSender(Session.java:74)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Session.createSender(Session.java:66)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.MessageProducerImpl.<init>(MessageProducerImpl.java:72)
    ... 4 more
javax.jms.JMSException: Session remotely closed
```

With the same code If I point to Azure service bus by setting the SB namespace and queue like below

`connectionfactory.SBCF = amqps://<Policy name>:<Sec. Key>@<ns>.servicebus.windows.net
queue.QUEUE = testq`

This works, messages are exchanged.

Here is the code if someone wants to try it

```
package com.stringcompany.Analyzer;

//SimpleSenderReceiver.java

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.ExceptionListener;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class SimpleSenderReceiver implements MessageListener {
    private static boolean runReceiver = true;
    private Connection connection;
    private Session sendSession;
    private Session receiveSession;
    private MessageProducer sender;
    private MessageConsumer receiver;
    private static Random randomGenerator = new Random();

public SimpleSenderReceiver() throws Exception {
    // Configure JNDI environment
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "D:\\Java\\Azure\\workspace\\Analyzer\\src\\main\\resources\\servicebus.properties");
    Context context = new InitialContext(env);

    // Lookup ConnectionFactory and Queue
    ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("SBCF");

    System.out.println("cf:"+cf);

    // Create Connection
    connection = cf.createConnection();
    System.out.println("connection :"+connection);

    connection.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListener() {

        public void onException(JMSException arg0) {
            System.err.println(arg0);

        }
    });
    connection.start();



    // Create sender-side Session and MessageProducer
    sendSession = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    System.out.println("Session open");


    Destination queue = (Destination) context.lookup("QUEUE");
    System.out.println("queue:"+queue);

    sender = sendSession.createProducer(queue);
    Queue q=(Queue) queue;
    System.out.println(sender.getDestination());
    System.out.println("sender:"+sender);
    if (runReceiver) {
        System.out.println("Waitng for new message");
        // Create receiver-side Session, MessageConsumer,and MessageListener
        receiveSession = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        receiver = receiveSession.createConsumer(queue);
        receiver.setMessageListener(this);
        connection.start();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        if ((args.length > 0) && args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("sendonly")) {
            runReceiver = false;
        }

        //System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","ssl");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","D:\\Java\\Azure\\workspace\\Analyzer\\src\\main\\resources\\SBKeystore.keystore");
        System.setProperty("log4j.configuration","D:\\Java\\Azure\\workspace\\Analyzer\\src\\main\\resources\\log4j.properties");
        SimpleSenderReceiver simpleSenderReceiver = new SimpleSenderReceiver();
        System.out
                .println("Press [enter] to send a message. Type 'exit' + [enter] to quit.");
        BufferedReader commandLine = new java.io.BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        while (true) {
            String s = "Message";//commandLine.readLine();
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                simpleSenderReceiver.close();
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                simpleSenderReceiver.sendMessage();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void sendMessage() throws JMSException {
    TextMessage message = sendSession.createTextMessage();
    message.setText("Test AMQP message from JMS");
    long randomMessageID = randomGenerator.nextLong() >>> 1;
    message.setJMSMessageID("ID:" + randomMessageID);
    sender.send(message);
    System.out.println("Sent message with JMSMessageID = "
            + message.getJMSMessageID());
}

public void close() throws JMSException {
    connection.close();
}

public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Received message with JMSMessageID = "
                + message.getJMSMessageID());
        message.acknowledge();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

  }
```

[image]

Comment: can you please share the working code for windows server service bus, with your pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi we had the same problems and thankfully MS updated their documentation to show how to do this correctly. :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn574799.aspx

Comment: great, When I get some time I will check what was I doing wrong and will update this question. Thanks for sharing this info.

Comment: The main thing is the connection string is completely different than what I thought it would be

Comment: @Sentinel can you please share gist of your working code, I am facing same issue and used the sample code from ms-website but its still not working, here is my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769498/windows-service-bus-error-peer-did-not-create-remote-endpoint-for-link-target)

Comment: @hr-tis Sorry it was a long time ago. I have the feeling it was something to do with connection string format.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer to the question is as you should URL Encode the SASPolicyKey.

```
connectionfactory.SBCF = amqps://[SASPolicyName]:[SASPolicyKey]@[namespace].servicebus.windows.net
```

Where SASPolicyKey should be URL-Encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have sorted the first issue (Java Message Broker API not supporting SAS endpoint), by writing a wrapper which will seamlessly work with existing API. You can get the library from [this](https://github.com/Dhana-Krishnasamy/ServiceBusForWindows-SASWrapper) GitHub repository.  With this, I can develop/test my Java application on local service bus environment and host it on Azure / On-Premise Service Bus farm.

https://github.com/Dhana-Krishnasamy/ServiceBusForWindows-SASWrapper

Answer (score 0):

AMQP 1.0 is supported with Service Bus 1.1 for windows server. Basically there are two differences between the cloud and on-prem usage of AMQP in ServiceBus:
1. Addressing: You will need to build an AMQP connection strings (and will need DNS in case you're looking for HA)
2. Authentication: You will need to use domain joined accounts as ACS is not there on-prem. You will also need to distribute your SB certificate to your clients.

Comment: I think this is what I tried, I will give it another try, Thx for confirming that AMQPO is supported on SB for Windows.

Comment: I have updated my question with what error I get and the code I run. Let me know if my addressing is wrong ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? We are experiencing the same problem with 1.1 Server SB. Java app cannot connect despite using the same shared secret access that works from .NET. What should the connection string look like and how can the Java app authenticate?

Comment: OK, update. We can connect. When sending message though we get "Peer did not create remote endpoint for link"

Comment: Ignore the previous comments pls, see my answer. MS posted some new info.

Answer (score 0):

The sender and receiver Queues you will have to configure differently. Here is an example of my working configuration (servicebus.properties):

connectionfactory.SBCF = amqps://$PolicyName:$UrlEncodedKey@$Your-EventHub-NamespaceName.servicebus.windows.net

queue.EventHubSender=$YourEventHubName
queue.EventHubReceiver=$YourEventHubName/ConsumerGroups/$YourConsumerGroupName/Partitions/1

Replace appropriately your own '$' items in there.
The Shared Policy Key has to be URL encoded.
Make sure that your sender will reference the 'EventHubSender' defined in this config and the receiver will reference the 'EventHubReciever'.

Answer (score -1):

Grab the Azure Java SDK from http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/ and then follow this guide: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/how-to-guides/service-bus-queues/

Comment: The example in your second link doent work on SB for Windows Server, because example use ACS auth which is not supported on SB for Windows Server (my point 1)