# windows service bus error: Peer did not create remote endpoint for link, target:,

Tags: java, amqp, servicebus, windows-server

I am trying to connect to windows service bus using, [the example provided on microsoft website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn574799.aspx), trying to connect the service bus using AMQP from java

```
private String SbConnStrACS = "amqps://" + SbUsername + ":" + encode(SbPassword) + "@" + SbDomain;
private String SbQueueName = SbNamespace + "/testq";
```

I am using below versions of libraries

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
    <artifactId>qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms</artifactId>
    <version>0.22</version>
</dependency>
```

but I am getting error:

```
 javax.jms.JMSException: Peer did not create remote endpoint for link, target: sbns/test
at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.MessageProducerImpl.<init>(MessageProducerImpl.java:77)
at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.SessionImpl.createProducer(SessionImpl.java:348)
at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.SessionImpl.createProducer(SessionImpl.java:63)
at test.servicebus.SimpleSenderReceiver.<init>(SimpleSenderReceiver.java:36)
at test.servicebus.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

For the exact same error on Azure Service bus is to [remove `partitioned flag` from the queues](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2015/02/15/azure-service-bus-amqp-using-java-sdk-peer-did-not-create-remote-endpoint-for-link-target-amqp_queue/), but for windows service bus I am not able to find any such flag

What else can I try??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below change in registry resolved the issue (thanks to Microsoft support for this)

> reg delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v
>   SchSendAuxRecord /f
>
> reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v
>   SchSendAuxRecord /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f